# Subscribing to mocha events for reporting

Tags: javascript, node.js, mocha.js

I'm trying to use `json-cov` reporter from [mocha](http://mochajs.org/#reporters). I'm hoping that I could register to json emitter and grab the output to write to a json file. I found a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660916/how-can-i-subscribe-to-mocha-suite-events) but the solution is not working for me. So below is what I have from the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18660916/how-can-i-subscribe-to-mocha-suite-events). Test passes but the console log statement is not printed as expected. This is how I'm running the test `mocha -t 60s --reporter json-cov`. Am I missing anything?

```
var Mocha = require('mocha'),
  mocha = new Mocha(),
  runner = mocha.run(),
  testsPassed = 0;

var onTestPassedHandler = function(e){
    testsPassed++;
    console.log("onTestPassedHandler - title: " + e.title + " - total:" + testsPassed);
};

runner.on("pass", onTestPassedHandler);
```

## Edit 1:

I got it working now. I guess I didn't understand method of extending reports. This documentation [here](https://github.com/mochajs/mocha/wiki/Third-party-reporters) helped. All I did was created my own reporter under node_modules called mocha-latte and put below contents in `node_modules/mocha-latte/index.js` and run tests like `mocha -t 60s --reporter mocha-latte` and everything worked as expected. Mocha will pass the runner and you could just listen to the events, sweet!

```
module.exports = function (runner) {
    var testsPassed = 0;
    var onTestPassedHandler = function(e){
        testsPassed++;
        console.log("onTestPassedHandler - title: " + e.title + " - total:" + testsPassed);
    };
    runner.on("pass", onTestPassedHandler);
}
```